# Is there a word that describes this: "he did something for me but he always mentions that"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Is there any word I can use in this circumstance:

> Someone needs help, you help them, but every time you see them, you remind them of the favor you've done them.

I mean is there an adjective I can use for the guy who repeatedly remind you of the favor they've done to you?

Comment: Can't think of a single word but depending on the context there are numerous idiomatic expressions to convey that: *hold it over him*, *lord it over him*, *hark back to it* etc etc

Comment: He *never lets you forget* is another expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that they did the original favour *begrudgingly*, so you could perhaps describe them that way - *begrudging*.

Someone who likes to boast about the 'good' they've done may be called a *virtue signaller*.

When someone is still expecting praise or gratitude for something done a long time ago, we sometimes say they are '*still dining out*' on it.